# Смысл строк в коде функции min

Tags: python-3.x

Нижеприведенный код является частью кода ф-ции min. Хотел бы прояснить для себя смысл отдельных записей:

1. Конструкция ifargs: означает,что мы передали в нашу функцию больше одной переменной (т.к. у нас есть закрепленная переменная в функции 'arg')?
2. для чего мы вводим переменную со значением false? Что это будет значить и как может использоваться?
3. переменная iterable будет включать в себя значения, кот. не вошли в arg?

Спасибо.

```
def min(arg, *args, key=None, **kwargs):
    if args:
        flag = False
        iterable = args
        if key is None:
            vmin, kmin = arg, arg
        else:
            vmin, kmin = arg, key(arg)
```

Comment: Условие `if arg` проверяет, передано ли в функцию вообще что-нибудь (функция могла быть вызвана вообще без параметров: `min()`). По 2 и 3 пункту - приведенного кода недостаточно, чтобы понять как эти переменные используются.

Comment: Точнее да, `if args` проверяет, что переданы другие позиционные аргументы кроме `arg`.